# Excel: Match a value from a column and then collect values from a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to enter a value in G2, then it will search from column A. In the picture attached it is A26 cell. Then I need to fill up G4 and G5 cell from column B and D.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following formulae. For Item1, enter in G4:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH($G$2,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

For Item2, enter in G5:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$5,MATCH($G$2,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

Adjust the cells to accommodate the columns

[image]